# How to make tables appear with desired kableExtra theme on pkgdown website?

Tags: r, kableextra, pkgdown

I am using `pkgdown` to build my package website. However, when utilizing `kableExtra::kable_classic` for my final table shown in my website in the [Customizing with KableExtra](https://michaeltopper1.github.io/panelsummary/articles/panelsummary.html#customizing-with-kableextra) section of my vignette titled "Introduction to panelsummary", I expected my website to return a LaTeX booktabs style as it shows in the [`kableExtra` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html) under the table name: "Recreating booktabs style table".

However, as shown, I do not get such a result—the table has undesirable lines, is not centered (which can't seem to be fixed with `fig.align` in the RMD file), and really doesn't look similar at all to the booktabs style I was expecting.

I am expecting this might have to do with the bootstrap theme that is being used...but I have not found a good help file that explains how to deal with this sort of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is indeed that the HTML environment `<table>` generated by `kable()` inherits CSS properties (in particular, properties of the `table` CSS class) from the vignette's bootstrap theme that have precedence over kableExtra styles.

I don't think this is solvable using kable/kableExtra functions but you could use jQuery to remove the table class from those tables that have the `.lightable-classic` class and fix the display style. Simply include the code chunk below:

````r
```{js}
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".lightable-classic").removeClass("table").css("display", "table");
});
```
````

The regression summary should then look like this:

[image]